# The meaning of "to" in these two sentences

Tags: prepositions

1. **To** my surprise, he made it.
2. **To my mind**, recent events have only underlined the need for the United Nations.

What is the meaning of "to " in each sentence?

How to understand the preposition "to"?

Comment: Sentence #2 is not correct because it needs an **"a"** before **"clever"**. But still it's very strange. *I think he is a cleaver boy* or *To me he is a clever boy* (this one is not good either)

Comment: Yes, I made a mistake, and I will use another sentence.

Comment: Entry #15 and #16 is relevant. [Go to this link](http://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/to_2)

Answer (score 1):

To my surprise, to her astonishment, to my horror (mostly at the beginning of a sentence)

- I discovered to my horror that my passport was missing. Longman DCE, to, no. 16

This special use of the preposition to is very old and was already used in Latin. In Latin grammars this use is treated in the chapter dative as dative finalis, ie the dative indicates what effect was produced.

To my surprise I found ... equivalent to: I was very surprised when I found...

To my horror - I was horrified when ...

Already in Latin it was difficult to explain this special use of dative, ie
it is not possible or very difficult to find a formula that could explain the dative.

The only way I have found to make the dative plausible is:

- I lost my passport which led to my horror.

Shortening and fronting might produce:

- To my horror I lost my passport.

In a lot of languages the dative of effect was simply imitated by authors in written language, eg in German and in English. The dative of effect is not typical for spoken language.

Sentence 2 is not typical of dative of effect. This "to my mind" has the sense of "in my view", but it might be modelled after the structure of dative of effect.